# In memory caching in ASP.NET MVC 5 is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, memorycache

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project. In my project, I am doing in memory caching to some data for better performance. What I understand about in memory caching is that it cache data on server, so no matter who the client is, in the next request, it load the data from cache not from database and then send back to clients. I am doing in memory caching in ASP.NET MVC 5 and it is not working.

This is the GetRegions method I am caching:

```
public IEnumerable<Region> GetRegions(){
    ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    if(cache.Get("regions")==null)
    {
        IEnumerable<Region> regions = db.Regions;
        cache.Add("regions", regions, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
        return regions;
    }
    else
    {
        IEnumerable<Region> regions = (IEnumerable<Region>)cache.Get("regions");
        return regions;
    }
}
```

According to the above code, in the first request `cache.Get("regions")` is going to be null. But in the second request, it should not be null. But whenever I access that method, `cache.Get("regions")` is always null. Is the way I am doing in memory caching correct?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've got should work, though it is not entirely correct (it leaves open the very small possibility of the cache expiring between checking and using), though as your expiry is long I suspect this isn't what's happening here.  To correct your code:

```
public IEnumerable<Region> GetRegions()
{
    ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    const string key = "regions";

    IEnumerable<Region> regions = cache.Get(key) as IEnumerable<Region>;
    if (regions == null)
    {
        regions = db.Regions;
        cache.Add(key, regions, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
    }
    return regions;
}
```

I'm not sure this is going to fix your issue though!

Comment: I checked using break point. But it is not working. What I did was I access from firefox as first request. It was null. Then I open chrome and made second request. It was still null when I made second request with chrome. Actually it should not be null. Right?